# How to make a script that press a button scheduled time on a website(like pg down or space)?

Tags: javascript, browser, automation, refresh, keypress

I stream on youtube and I have OBS Studio which has a built-in browser.

I would like to know what is a suitable code if I want to have a pressed space button in every 20 seconds on that website automatically?

Comment: Look into `dispatchEvent` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) and already answered questions (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this but doesn't work (now 2 sec for easy testing)

```
$(window).load(function()  {
var e = $.Event('keydown', { keyCode: 32 });// space key
setInterval(function() {
$(document).trigger(e);
         }, 2000);
```

});